# Producing just network files from BiG-SCAPE

Tags: clustering, parameters

I was wondering if anyone knows off-hand if there is a way to run BiG-SCAPE without producing the svg or html files? All I want is the networking files (which I can play with in CytoScape).

There isn't anything obvious from reading the parameters section in [the wiki](https://github.com/medema-group/BiG-SCAPE/wiki/) but perhaps I just missed it? Maybe like a minimal mode or something similar?

Normally I would simply delete them, but I'm running around 20 000 BGCs through it. And I thought it would save time and disk space if those files are just never written out. I'm simultaneously trying out bigslice but the documentation is surprisingly tricky to follow.